# 5 Variable K-Map with Don't Cares

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

I stumbled upon this question and I tried doing it but my solution seemed very complicated and I wasn't sure if I grouped everything correctly or, if I did and wrote the correct expression, how to minimize it to the answer given in the textbook.

Here's the question:

[image]

What I did was I tried to draw the largest squares while also meeting the area condition.

Thanks!

Comment: Need something as this for verifying? http://www.32x8.com/var4.html

Comment: Did you carefully prepare your tables and then double-check them?

Comment: Leah, are you there? I really think you need to re-check your tables. They are NOT correct.

Comment: So you have 23 1's and X's of 32 states.  This leaves 9 0's.  You have 11!  Recheck your Tables!

Answer (score 2):

You are used to reading these K-maps with 000 001 011 ... and humans are not good at binary.

[image]

Instead note where the variables take a true/false value and mark out regions as shown below. The minterms are shown in boxes.

[image]

---

Let me read the red one on the left for you:

It crosses the boundary of `A` and crosses into `A'`, so variable `A` is discarded.

It crosses the boundaries for `B` and `E` as well.

It lies in the region `C'D'`.

Rest of these, I leave for you as an exercise. Each of these blocks has 8 minterms/dontcares in them, so there will be two variables left for each.

Answer (score 1):

Your k-map is pretty much a mess. Nothing is really right about it. Perhaps you got confused by ordering things in binary order? Not sure.

First thing to do is to generate a table of values, in binary order since that's easier to translate from your starting point:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\overset{X_1 = 0}{
\begin{smallmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\hline
X_2&X_3&X_4&X_5&F\\
\hline
0&0&0&0 & 1\\
0&0&0&1 & 1\\
0&0&1&0 & 0\\
0&0&1&1 & 1\\
0&1&0&0 & 1\\
0&1&0&1 & X\\
0&1&1&0 & 1\\
0&1&1&1 & X\\
1&0&0&0 & 1\\
1&0&0&1 & 1\\
1&0&1&0 & 0\\
1&0&1&1 & 1\\
1&1&0&0 & X\\
1&1&0&1 & 1\\
1&1&1&0 & 1\\
1&1&1&1 & X
\end{array}
\end{smallmatrix}}
&&&&&&&&&&&
\overset{X_1 = 1}{
\begin{smallmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\hline
X_2&X_3&X_4&X_5&F\\
\hline
0&0&0&0 & 1\\
0&0&0&1 & X\\
0&0&1&0 & 0\\
0&0&1&1 & 1\\
0&1&0&0 & 1\\
0&1&0&1 & 1\\
0&1&1&0 & 1\\
0&1&1&1 & X\\
1&0&0&0 & 1\\
1&0&0&1 & 1\\
1&0&1&0 & 0\\
1&0&1&1 & 0\\
1&1&0&0 & 0\\
1&1&0&1 & 0\\
1&1&1&0 & 0\\
1&1&1&1 & 0
\end{array}
\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}
$$

Then you need to reorder them so that they are easier to move to the k-map. Each block of four rows below now readily corresponds directly to a column in the k-map so that there is much less chance of making a transcription mistake:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
&&&&&\overset{X_1 = 0}{
\begin{smallmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\hline
X_2&X_3&&X_4&X_5&&F\\
\hline
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\phantom{X_2}&\phantom{X_3}&&\phantom{X_4}&\phantom{X_5}&&\phantom{F}\\
0&0 && 0&0 && 1\\
0&0 && 0&1 && 1\\
0&0 && 1&1 && 1\\
0&0 && 1&0 && 0\\
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\phantom{X_2}&\phantom{X_3}&&\phantom{X_4}&\phantom{X_5}&&\phantom{F}\\
0&1 && 0&0 && 1\\
0&1 && 0&1 && X\\
0&1 && 1&1 && X\\
0&1 && 1&0 && 1\\
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\phantom{X_2}&\phantom{X_3}&&\phantom{X_4}&\phantom{X_5}&&\phantom{F}\\
1&1 && 0&0 && X\\
1&1 && 0&1 && 1\\
1&1 && 1&1 && X\\
1&1 && 1&0 && 1\\
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\phantom{X_2}&\phantom{X_3}&&\phantom{X_4}&\phantom{X_5}&&\phantom{F}\\
1&0 && 0&0 && 1\\
1&0 && 0&1 && 1\\
1&0 && 1&1 && 1\\
1&0 && 1&0 && 0
\end{array}
\end{smallmatrix}}
&&&&&&&&&
\overset{X_1 = 1}{
\begin{smallmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\hline
X_2&X_3&&X_4&X_5&&F\\
\hline
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\phantom{X_2}&\phantom{X_3}&&\phantom{X_4}&\phantom{X_5}&&\phantom{F}\\
0&0 && 0&0 && 1\\
0&0 && 0&1 && X\\
0&0 && 1&1 && 1\\
0&0 && 1&0 && 0\\
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\phantom{X_2}&\phantom{X_3}&&\phantom{X_4}&\phantom{X_5}&&\phantom{F}\\
0&1 && 0&0 && 1\\
0&1 && 0&1 && 1\\
0&1 && 1&1 && X\\
0&1 && 1&0 && 1\\
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\phantom{X_2}&\phantom{X_3}&&\phantom{X_4}&\phantom{X_5}&&\phantom{F}\\
1&1 && 0&0 && 0\\
1&1 && 0&1 && 0\\
1&1 && 1&1 && 0\\
1&1 && 1&0 && 0\\
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
\phantom{X_2}&\phantom{X_3}&&\phantom{X_4}&\phantom{X_5}&&\phantom{F}\\
1&0 && 0&0 && 1\\
1&0 && 0&1 && 1\\
1&0 && 1&1 && 0\\
1&0 && 1&0 && 0
\end{array}
\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}
$$

Then you populate the k-map directly from the above reordered table (it's now very easy to do):

[image]

Finally, you identify the largest groupings, one by one, to get:

[image]

You made a number of mistakes. I'll leave it to you to identify those and then understand how you made those mistakes.